# Divide count of Table 1 by count of Table 2 on the same time interval in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I have two tables with IDs and time stamps. Table 1 has two columns: ID and created_at. Table 2 has two columns: ID and post_date. I'd like to create a chart in Tableau that displays the Number of Records in Table 1 divided by Number of Records in Table 2, by week. How can I achieve this?

Comment: HAve you joined tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way might be to use Custom SQL like this to create a new data source for your visualization:

```
SELECT created_table.created_date,
   created_table.created_count,
   posted_table.posted_count
FROM (SELECT TRUNC (created_at) AS created_date, COUNT (*) AS created_count
      FROM Table1) created_table
   LEFT JOIN
   (SELECT TRUNC (post_date) AS posted_date, COUNT (*) AS posted_count
      FROM Table2) posted_table
       ON created_table.created_date = posted_table.posted_date
```

This would give you dates and counts from both tables for those dates, which you could group using Tableau's date functions in the visualization. I made `created_table` the first part of the left join on the assumption that some records would be created and not posted, but you wouldn't have posts without creations. If that isn't the case you will want a different join.

Comment: Thank you for your help It worked .i just changed trunc to be week() as i'm using mysql and wanted my results to be grouped by week:
select * from (select count(*) as tasks_count , week(created_at) as created_week from table1
group by week(created_at)) tasks_table left join (
select  count(*) as jobs_count , week(post_date) as posted_week from table2
group by week(post_date)) posts_table
on posts_table.posted_week=tasks_table.tasks_week